# Suspension broken - attempting triage

Tags: suspension

My wife's Honda Jazz hadn't been driven for a few days, and on driving out of our street yesterday there was a large clang and the front right corner dropped an inch.

Turning the wheel lock to lock I get 3 major clangs - and looking up under the wheel arch I see that while the front left coil spring unit smoothly turns, with the top of the spring turning as you'd expect, the top of the front right is stationary until the steering wheel is turned a fair bit, and then it suddenly jerks round with a loud mechanical clang.

I can't see any breaks, but I'm assuming the spring or mount must have a break somewhere. Before I take it to the garage, is there anything I may have missed in terms of diagnosis, or any causes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diagnosis from the garage was relatively simple:

Corrosion had meant that the cap holding the suspension spring didn't turn (and probably hasn't for some time) so steering has been twisting the spring until it finally failed. So it snapped right at the top, and when steering the loose end catching on the rest of the spring is what causes the clang.